# Bash Deployment of PostgreSQL - Installtion Trouble

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, linode

I am trying to build postgreSQL from source on my Debian 6.0 server using a bash shell script but I am running into problems. This is the code I have made so far:

```
# Initial
    apt-get update
    apt-get -y install aptitude bzip2 libbz2-dev git-core
    aptitude -y install sudo python-all-dev python-setuptools libxml2-dev libgeoip-dev libxslt1-dev uuid-dev gcc automake autoconf libpcre3-dev libssl-dev unzip zip python-psycopg2 libpq-dev wget make libreadline-dev
    aptitude -y full-upgrade 

# POSTGRESQL
###############################

# Postgresql Download & Install
    wget http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v8.4.6/postgresql-8.4.6.tar.gz -P /tmp
    mkdir /tmp/postgresql
    tar xzf /tmp/postgresql-8.4.6.tar.gz -C "/tmp/postgresql"
    cd /tmp/postgresql/
    mkdir /usr/local/pgsql
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pgsql
    cd /usr/local/pgsql
    make
    make install

# Add User
    useradd -s /bin/false "postgresql_user"
    chown "postgresql_user" usr/local/pgsql

# Clean Up
    rm  /tmp/postgresql-8.4.6.tar.gz
    rm  /tmp/postgresql

# Create Database
    echo "CREATE ROLE PSQL LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'PASS';" | sudo -u postgresql_user usr/local/pgsql
    sudo -u postgresql_user /opt/bin/createdb --owner PSQL DATADB
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
/root/StackScript: line 22: ./configure: No such file or directory                                    
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.                                          
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.                                                    
chown: cannot access `usr/local/pgsql': No such file or directory                                                                                  
sudo: usr/local/pgsql: command not found                                                              
sudo: /opt/bin/createdb: command not found
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please? If there is anything else obvious I have done incorrectly I am always open to hear about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you're doing wrong is compiling an old point release of an old major version. Why on earth would you be using 8.4.6 when there's 8.4.15, with quite a few significant bug fixes? See the [versioning policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). You shouldn't be using 8.4 for new deployments anyway, use the latest version for new deployments.

Even better, use the debian packages at [pgapt.debian.org](http://pgapt.debian.net/) rather than compiling yourself.

The immediate cause of the error is that unpacking the source tarball produces a directory like `postgresql-8.4.6` so you have `/tmp/postgresql/postgresql-8.4.6`. You're trying to execute the `configure` script in `/tmp/postgresql` not `/tmp/postgresql/postgresql-8.4.6`. `cd` into the created directory before running `configure`.